# Yii php : Remove duplicates in the database and update the duplicate row

Tags: php, yii, sql-update, duplicates, criteria

i'm using Yii php and i have a problem with duplicate entries in the database.

to demonstrate, suppose i have this:

```
id(pk) | parent_id | parent_name| is_male(boolean) | is_female(boolean)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      |     1     |parent1     | true             | false                
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2      |     1     |parent1     | false            | true
------------------------------------------------------------------------
3      |     2     |parent2     | false            | true
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Technically, the parent1 is the same, but used as both female and male. **Above is correct but inefficient**, the duplication is not necessary since they only pertain to the same parent. How do i **remove the duplicate parent1** and just update the first row **is_female** to **true**?

such as to result to :

```
id(pk) | parent_id | parent_name| is_male(boolean) | is_female(boolean)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      |     1     |parent1     | true             | true                
------------------------------------------------------------------------
3      |     2     |parent2     | false            | true
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do i do this programmatically in Yii php? Thanks!

Comment: I have a question - For id 1 both is_male and is_female is true?

Comment: in the first table, no...in the second yes...

the idea is to "merge" the row with id(pk) 1 and 2.. because they basically refer to the same thing which is parent1 with id both 1.

Comment: Please, do only one field "gender" for this. What the reason do it seperate?

Comment: the reason is that .. there is a textfield where users specify parents.. now, parent1 can either be used as male only, female only, or both, i have to have some sort of identifier.

Answer (score 0):

```
    in update mode loadModel query change means you no need to delete the duplicated , the first record will be get updated 

  Controller file
 ----------------    
          Function loadModel($id)
           {
    $where='id='.$id .' Group by parent_id '
    $model=Model()->find($where);
           }

    in view file 
    ------------
            <?php
            if($model->parent_id==1)  // when the parent_id is 1 the female field will visible , sure not  affect the created 
            {
             echo $form->textField($model, 'is_female'); ?>
            }

        ?>
```